# MYSQL sum of a column with some specific number of entries

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Hi I am trying to calculate the number of distinct accountids which appear more than once in the last three months from the following data; I would want 2 as a result of the query because test1@gmail.com and test2@gmail.com appears more than 1 time.

```
accountid         purchase  requesttime
test1@gmail.com   150       2017-01-01
test2@gmail.com   100       2017-01-01
test1@gmail.com   100       2017-01-01
test1@gmail.com   200       2017-01-01
test2@gmail.com   240       2017-01-01
test1@gmail.com   210       2017-01-01
test3@gmail.com   4         2017-01-01
test4@gmail.com   60        2017-01-01
```

Comment: Your stated requirement and your attempted query don't match. It would be helpful if you provided proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need two levels of aggregation.  The first returns the emails that meet the condition:

```
select n.account_id, count(*) as cnt
from ndsbulkstorage22 n
where requesttime >= CURRENT_DATE - interval 3 month
group by accountid
having count(*) > 1;
```

Then you can use this as a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select n.account_id, count(*) as cnt
      from ndsbulkstorage22 n
      where requesttime >= CURRENT_DATE - interval 3 month
      group by accountid
      having count(*) > 1
     ) n;
```

Answer (score -1):

This query will show a result 3 months before request time and some purchase field.

**MYSQL**

```
select accountid,sum(purchase) as your_sum,requesttime from tbl_sum 
where requesttime <=DATE_ADD(requesttime,INTERVAL -3 month) GROUP BY accountid,requesttime
```

**MSQL**

```
select accountid,sum(purchase) as your_sum,requesttime from tbl_sum 
where requesttime <=DATEADD(month,-3,requesttime) GROUP BY accountid,requesttim
```